# How to get data froma json in php (multidimensional array)

Tags: php, json, multidimensional-array

This is the data I work with:

```
{
    "jornadas": [
        {
            "partits": [
                {
                    "local": 1,
                    "visitante": 2
                },
                {
                    "local": 3,
                    "visitante": 4
                },
                {
                    "local": 5,
                    "visitante": 6
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "partits": [
                {
                    "local": 1,
                    "visitante": 2
                },
                {
                    "local": 3,
                    "visitante": 4
                },
                {
                    "local": 5,
                    "visitante": 6
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "partits": [
                {
                    "local": 1,
                    "visitante": 2
                },
                {
                    "local": 3,
                    "visitante": 4
                },
                {
                    "local": 5,
                    "visitante": 6
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "partits": [
                {
                    "local": 1,
                    "visitante": 2
                },
                {
                    "local": 3,
                    "visitante": 4
                },
                {
                    "local": 5,
                    "visitante": 6
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "partits": [
                {
                    "local": 1,
                    "visitante": 2
                },
                {
                    "local": 3,
                    "visitante": 4
                },
                {
                    "local": 5,
                    "visitante": 6
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

And when it goes to php, I decode it and the print_f result is:

stdClass Object ( [jornadas] => Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [partits] => Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [local] => 2 [visitante] => 7 ) [1] => stdClass Object ( [local] => 3 [visitante] => 5 ) [2] => stdClass Object ( [local] => 4 [visitante] => 1 ) ) ) [1] => stdClass Object ( [partits] => Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [local] => 1 [visitante] => 7 ) [1] => stdClass Object ( [local] => 5 [visitante] => 4 ) [2] => stdClass Object ( [local] => 2 [visitante] => 3 ) ) ) [2] => stdClass Object ( [partits] => Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [local] => 3 [visitante] => 7 ) [1] => stdClass Object ( [local] => 4 [visitante] => 2 ) [2] => stdClass Object ( [local] => 1 [visitante] => 5 ) ) ) [3] => stdClass Object ( [partits] => Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [local] => 5 [visitante] => 7 ) [1] => stdClass Object ( [local] => 2 [visitante] => 1 ) [2] => stdClass Object ( [local] => 3 [visitante] => 4 ) ) ) [4] => stdClass Object ( [partits] => Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [local] => 4 [visitante] => 7 ) [1] => stdClass Object ( [local] => 1 [visitante] => 3 ) [2] => stdClass Object ( [local] => 5 [visitante] => 2 ) ) ) ) )

Well I'm overwhelmed, because I cannot retreive any data from this json. If you give me any advise, I'll be very grateful

Comment: it is a object. if you want it as an array then convert it.

Answer (score 6):

This answer assumes you are using the `json_decode` function of PHP.

You should decode it with the 2nd parameter as true:

```
json_decode($yourJSON, true);
```

This gives you an associative array instead of an stdClass object.

More information on the `json_decode` function:
http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php

Comment: Did you read that `when it goes to php, I decode it and the print_f result is:`?

Comment: I did and I assume he decodes it with json_decode, and if he did, he didn't set the 2nd parameter to true.

Answer (score 1):

try `foreach` after decode

```
$decode = json_decode($json, true); //decodes in associative array
foreach($decode['jornadas'] as $k=>$v) {
  foreach($v['partits'] as $k1=>$v1) {
     echo $v1['local'];
     echo $v1['visitante'];
  }
}
```